# Botón que funcione como CTROL+F

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, html5

Necesito agregar un botón en una web que abra la pop que habitualmente lanza el **CTROL  + F**. Es posible?

Comment: ¿Deseas abrir una funcionalidad del navegador (búsqueda en la página) desde Javascript? Lamentablemente por motivos de seguridad eso no te será posible. En todo caso, podrías implementar tu propia versión de dicha funcionalidad. También podrías intentar usar el método **no estándar** [`Window.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find), pero has de revisar la compatibilidad con el navegador que vayas a utilizar. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente no puedes invocar el popup desde JS, ya que ésta funcionalidad es del browser.

Lo que se me ocurre es crear un modal y dentro colocar un input y un botón de búsqueda, es decir, simular tu propio popup e invocarlo cuando desees.

En cuanto a la funcionalidad de búsqueda, esa sí se puede acceder desde JS utilizando `window.find`:

```
<a href="#" onclick="find('texto a buscar');">Buscar</a>
```

Solamente revisa cuidadosamente la compatibilidad.

[Window.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find)